# PHP dynamic dropdown menu list - default value

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a default value for my dynamic drop down list. After the user selects one of the options, they submit and that value is stored as a variable in the next page that I can access using $_POST['land']

I have created the same dynamic list in the next page and want that 'land' to appear first in the dynamic drop down menu. So far this is just the main code to show the dynamic drop down list. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                { 
                    extract ($row);
                    echo "<option value='$place'>$place</option>\n";

                }
```

Comment: you want the previously selected option to be first in the list? wouldn't it be enough to have it pre-selected, using `<option selected="selected">$place</option>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            { 
                extract ($row);
                echo "<option value='$place' ";
                if($_POST['land'] == $place) {
                  echo "selected='selected'";
                }
                echo ">$place</option>\n";

            }
```

Comment: It's a little pedantic, but `selected="selected"` is better syntax to use.

Comment: @Grim... also, your username makes it read like I'm really hesitant to tell you anything :)

Comment: i did look this up on w3c and they said it's valid html5 to have just the attribute-name. but i'd suggest to have name and value, as well. =)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand you want the item chosen on first page to appear as the default item in the second page.

Use this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
    extract ($row);
    echo "<option value='$place'";
    echo ((isset($_POST['land']) && $_POST['land']==$place)?'selected="selected"':'');
    echo ">$place</option>\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
   extract ($row);
   $select = (isset($_POST['land']) && $_POST['land'] == $place)?"selected='selected'":"";
   echo "<option value='$place' $select >$place</option>\n";
}
```